# MySQL Single DISTINCT Column

Tags: mysql

This table has host and interface columns     `UNIQUE combination`
*** EDIT: This table also has a auto incremented unique id, Sorry I should have mentioned this before **

```
| host....  | interface..... | value      |
+-----------+----------------+------------+
| Host-0    | Interface-15   |    490     |
| Host-2    | Interface-4    |    490     |
| Host-3    | Interface-0    |    495     |
| Host-3    | Interface-7    |    485     |
| Host-5    | Interface-13   |    495     | 
| Host-5    | Interface-17   |    495     |
| Host-10   | Interface-9    |    490     |
| Host-11   | Interface-11   |    495     |
| Host-12   | Interface-9    |    485     |
| Host-12   | Interface-17   |    490     |
```

I want to select the Top 10 by value for     `DISTINCT host`

I Tried:

```
SELECT host, interface, value FROM table ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 10;

| host.... | interface..... | value     |
+----------+----------------+-----------+
| Host-0   | Interface-15   |   490     |
| Host-5   | Interface-17   |   495     |
| Host-5   | Interface-13   |   495     |
| Host-11  | Interface-11   |   495     |
| Host-3   | Interface-0    |   495     |
| Host-0   | Interface-15   |   490     |
| Host-12  | Interface-17   |   490     |
| Host-10  | Interface-9    |   490     |
| Host-2   | Interface-4    |   490     |
| Host-3   | Interface-7    |   485     |
| Host-12  | Interface-9    |   485     |
```

But I have duplicates in host. I need to show only a distinct host with the highest value

For Example:
Host-5 Interface-17 495
Host 12 Interface-17 490

I have also tried:

```
SELECT
  host,
  interface,
  value
FROM table
GROUP BY host
ORDER BY value DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

But, I'm not getting the hosts with the highest value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in various ways.  Here is the `not exists` way:

```
SELECT host, interface, value 
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.host = t.host and t2.value > t.value
                 )
ORDER BY value DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

This says:  "Get me all rows in the table with the same host that have no higher values for that host."

You can also do this with `group by`, using the `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` trick:

```
select host, substring_index(group_concat(interface order by value desc), ',', 1) as interface,
       max(value)
from table t
group by host
order by max(value) desc
limit 10;
```

Comment: I'm still getting duplicate hosts

Comment: This happens because you have several records with same value for interface/host couples. thus you have to select only the first interface in your selected records. I updated my own answer to allow you doing this.

Comment: @MChiru . . . The second solution will return only one row per host.  If you had an auto-incremented unique id on each row, then you could use the `not exists` more easily.

Comment: This table also has a auto incremented unique id, Sorry I should have mentioned this before

Comment: The second solution works (with a minor change) : select host, substring_index(group_concat(interface order by value desc), ',', 1) as interface,
       max(value)
from table t
group by host
order by     MAX(value) desc
limit 10;

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT host, interface, value
FROM table t1
WHERE value = (SELECT MAX(value) 
    FROM table t2 
    WHERE t2.host = t1.host)
AND interface = (SELECT 
    t3.interface
    FROM table t3 
    WHERE t3.value = t1.value
    AND t3.host = t1.host limit 1)
ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: This Query is Not Working

Comment: This query is wrong.  I can understand the writing of it (a bit misguided), but the upvote I don't understand.

Comment: I would downvote  myself if i could. I updated my answer, I think this one fits